# Allendoerfer and Weil's generalization of Gauss-Bonnet Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, math-history, characteristic-classes

In Peter Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry* ([reference](https://download.tuxfamily.org/openmathdep/geometry_advanced/Riemannian_Geometry-Peterson.pdf), p. 98), he says that

> The theorem is now called the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet Theorem despite the fact that Allendoerfer and Weil were the first to prove it in complete generality in higher dimensions.

But on Wikepedia ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem)), it is said that

> In 1943, Carl B. Allendoerfer and André Weil proved a special case for extrinsic manifolds. In a classic paper published in 1944, Shiing-Shen Chern proved the theorem in full generality connecting global topology with local geometry.

Who was really the first to prove the "full generality"? I don't have enough knowledge of differential geometry to judge it myself, but I want to know the history.

Comment: If I read the [paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/allenweil.pdf) of Allendoerfer and Weil correctly (which Wiki failed to cite), the statement in Wiki is just false. They proved already the general version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every Riemannian manifold $(X,g)$ can be isometrically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^N$ for $N$ sufficiently large. So in principle, when one wants to prove something about Riemannian manifolds, it suffices to consider isometrically embedded submanifolds $X\subset\mathbb{R}^N$. However, this is not the most natural way to study the geometric object $(X,g)$, because it requires a choice of embedding into $\mathbb{R}^N$. Hence, this is called "extrinsic". The text states that Carl B. Allendoerfer and André Weil proved the theorem in full generality for embedded submanifolds $X\subset\mathbb{R}^N$, and thus for every Riemannian manifold - but not in the most natural way, because it requires a choice of embedding.

There is also a way to prove the same theorem without making reference to any embedding into Euclidean space. This is called "intrinsic", and the text states the Chern was the first to prove the theorem in full generality without making reference to such an embedding. Doing this does not prove anything new, because every Riemannian manifold can already be viewed as a submanifold of some $\mathbb{R}^N$. This is why the text says "despite
the fact that Allendoerfer and Weil were the first to prove it in complete generality
in higher dimensions." - Chern wasn't the first to prove the theorem, but he gave a more natural proof, which is why the result now bears his name.

Comment: I just want to point out that Nash embedding theorem is not available at the time.  Allendoerfer and Weil need to use a local isometric embedding of Cartan and prove a local version of the theorem first.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks.

Comment: @ArcticChar Are you saying that Allendoerfer and Weil's proof wasn't considered the full generality until Nash embedding theorem?

Comment: No, if you read their proof, they have to first prove a local version (for Riemannian manifold with polyhedra boundary) of the Gauss bonnet theorem, then apply a theorem of Cartan that every Riemannian manifold can be locally isometricaly embedded into euclidean space. They have proved the theorem in complete generality, but if Nash's embedding theorem was available, such local argument is not necessary. @DashengWang

Comment: The Cartan-Janet local isometric embeddings requires a real analytic Riemannian metric. How is it used to prove the theorem for a smooth metric?

Comment: @Deane: I think a smooth metric on a simplex can be approximated by real analytic. If the formula holds for the latter, it holds for the former by passing to the limit.

Answer (score 3):

1. As  Arctic Char on strike stated, Allendoerfer and Weil proved in 1943 the theorem in full generality, in the contrary to what is written in Wikipedia. They were the first to do that, to the best of my knowledge.
2. Their proof used a result on existence of isometric imbeddings of Riemannian manifolds into Euclidean space available at the time (which is weaker than the Nash theorem).
3. In 1944 Chern gave another proof which did not use any imbeddings into Euclidean space. However Chern's proof worked only for closed manifolds, while Allendoerfer and Weil proof worked in greater generality: for manifolds with boundary and corners.

Comment: So the wiki claim is exactly the opposite of the truth :-?

Comment: Yes, I think so.